# Add/Remove elements via onclick

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension written in pure JS which is basically composed of functions which append data to links on the page.

An example of the functions which basically just appends a click integer to the link element passed in from another function:

```
function addCounttoLinks(link, counts) {
    var clicks = counts.split(":")[1].split(",")[0].trim();
    var count = document.createTextNode((" (" + clicks + ")"));
    var dspan = document.createElement("span");
    dspan.appendChild(count);
    dspan.style.fontSize = "10px"; dspan.style.textAlign = "center";
    link.appendChild(dspan); 
}
```

What is the most efficient way to execute/unexecute these functions, so that I can implement a "on/off" button for the user to click which would add/remove the data appended by the extension. Is the only solution to write functions to remove the previously created elements?

Comment: Add a class to the extra element. Then modify the style rule for the class to make all elements with that class visible or not.

Comment: is this really a chrome extension ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a class on the `span` (say, `my-nifty-extension-extra` — you want it to be fairly unlikely to clash with something else), then add a class to `body` (say, `hide-my-nifty-extension`) when hiding the data, and remove it when showing it. Then use this style rule:

```
body.hide-my-nifty-extension span.my-nifty-extension-extra {
    display: none;
}
```

E.g., just before your `appendChild`:

```
dspan.className = "my-nifty-extension-extra";
```

And then:

```
function showExtraData() {
    document.body.classList.remove('hide-my-nifty-extension');
}

function hideExtraData() {
    document.body.classList.add('hide-my-nifty-extension');
}
```

(One of the joys of writing a Chrome extension is that you know you have things like `classList`.)